# Including Styles and JS files to work ON my plugin interface

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

Hey WordPress community,

I've been having a couple of issues with trying to add a stylesheet and a JavaScript file which run on my plugin interface.

So far i have this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','dlm_scritps_init');

function dlm_scritps_init() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'dlm-scripts', plugins_url( 'data-layer-plugin/js/dlm-window.js', __FILE__ ));
}
```

Esstinally what i need the JavaScript file todo is when this button is clicked on the plugin interface then a form pops up with certian fields and a choice to add custom fields, all these fields are just textboxes.

Once the user has entered their respected data, then they simply submit this data into the options.

[image]

above is the button that will be clicked to show the form.

SO how would i go about enqueuing this JavaScript file to run the code once this button is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Well after a bit of better searching i found the answer,

```
function my_enqueue($hook) {
    if ( 'settings_page_data-layer-management' != $hook ) {
        return;
    }

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugins_url( 'js/dlm-window.js', __FILE__ ));
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

to explain just incase anyone has this issue.

what i had earlier was a 'front-end' hook which is just  `wp_enqueue_scripts`

for a back end, you need to use the admin hook `admin_enqueue_scripts` for your add action.

Next was trying to find the correct page hook. Luckily wordpress being helpfull in ports a $hook into the function, a simple if statement can then be used to determine which page to run the script on.

if you have problems finding your plugin hook, simple `echo $hook` to find out what yours is.

full documentation can be found here:

> http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts